# listen for returning UDP packets in bash

Tags: bash, sockets

I played around with bash(4.0.33) network support for learning purposes and tried to create a port scanner in bash. For TCP I opened a TCP/IP socket with

`exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.0.2.1/80`

and appropriate action was taken if the connection was refused or *connect* system call timed out. However, with UDP I'm easily able to send a packet with

`echo > /dev/udp/192.0.2.1/53`

but how to read returning packets from correct socket? I mean UDP datagram sent to 192.0.2.1 has source port from ephemeral port range and thus I do not know which socket in `/dev/udp/192.0.2.1/` directory should I read. Or isn't this doable without external utilities like *tcpdump*?

Comment: no offence, but even though you say this is for learning purposes, what's the point of learning something if you're never going to use it? bash is definitely not the right choice for this...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Actually, bash is an excellent tool for small and tiny IOT devices, bash handles UDP pretty well for many applications. and, BTW that was not the question: he was not asking for opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash's UDP support isn't great, and is compiled out on many distros (Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives especially). The recommended tool is netcat:

```
nc -u 192.0.2.1 53
```

Note: Use coproc or named pipes to read and write from the same netcat process. Don't send a packet first and try to catch the reply netcat.

Bash is really the wrong language for this though. Consider using Python, which handles both UDP and binary data way better, with just a couple of more lines of code.

Comment: Could you explain the usage of named pipe in this case? Did you mean to write UDP packet into named pipe and then use the named pipe as stdin for `nc`? If yes, then why is this approach better than redirecting UDP packet directly into `nc`?

Comment: You can use coprocs or named pipes for bidirectional communication with a process. If you just want to send one packet and receive one reply, you don't need it.

Answer (score -2):

"bash is definitely not the right choice for this"
"Bash is really the wrong language for this though"
Not sure why this is asserted (depending on disto). This works for me on a pi-Z-W:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do 
  nc -lu 16523 | (read line; 
  echo $line
  cmd=${line:0:9}
  echo $cmd
  if [ "$cmd" == "Send Date" ] ; then
    dt="!!D$(date +%y%m%d)"
    echo $dt > /dev/udp/192.168.2.165/16523
  elif [ "$cmd" == "Send Time" ] ; then
    tm="!!T$(date +%H%M%S)"
    echo $tm
    echo $tm > /dev/udp/192.168.2.165/16523
  else
    sleep 1s
    echo $line >> /home/pi/udp16523.log
  fi)
done
```

Then another process can, say hourly, send the time with
echo "!!T$(date +%H%M%S)" > /dev/udp/192.168.2.165/16523
I did have to turn off history expansion with "set H+" in /etc/rc.local to handle the unexpected (by me) expansion of ! within quotes.